# Makemigrations: ValueError: <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model

Tags: django, django-migrations

I struggle with migrations.
I have created a model fine, with a model named 'RecipeIngredient', run migration
and all is good.

I decide to rename it to 'Ingredient', and change the only two places in models.py where it is mentioned:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    fooditems = models.ManyToManyField(Fooditem, through='Ingredient', through_fields=('recipe', 'foodit'), )
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Calories')


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foodit = models.ForeignKey(Fooditem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    q_set = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, default=1)
```

When i migrate, I have the error:
`ValueError: <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x000001B1FDE8B550> contains a lazy reference to Fityfeed.recipeingredient, but app 'Fityfeed' doesn't provide model 'recipeingredient'.`

I would like to understand the logic in migrations: I can see that in the old migrations there is still
a 'RecipeIngredient' of course , am I supposed to change /delete old migrations? That creates all sort of problems.

Or maybe the cause is somewhere else, where could the old name be present in the project?

I add here the migration failing: it seems fine to me:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name='RecipeIngredient',
            new_name='Ingredient',
        ),
    ]
```

Thanks a lot for your help

D